# What is an efficient way to get a look-at direction from either a quaternion or a transformation matrix?

Tags: rotation, matrix, quaternion

So, I have an object in my custom engine (C++), with a column-major transform in world space. I'm using a package that takes a look-at direction as an input. What's the most efficient way to get a look-at direction from this transform? Do I extract the rotation matrix? Do I try to extract a quaternion?

Comment: Presumably you tried just multiplying your forward direction (eg (0, 0, 1, 0) if your convention is that z+ is the forward axis) by your matrix or quaternion? Do the results you get that way differ from what you need?

Comment: The columns of the matrix are the basis vectors of the transformed space (expressed in untransformed coordinates), so you only need to extract the column that points to the look-at object. A way to do that is to just multiply by a vector from the standard basis, e.g. as DMGregory suggested, (0, 0, 1, 0) picks out just the third column (you can try it on paper to see why).

Comment: @DMGregory They do not, I was just wondering if there was a more efficient way. Just pulling out the third column directly might save me some clock cycles!

Comment: If grabbing the third column gets what you need, I'd encourage you or @FilipMilovanović to post that as an Answer below. 

Comment: BTW, by column I mean the column in the convention where you multiply a matrix on the left via a column vector on the right (in the mathematical notation). There's also a convention where a row vector on the left is multiplied by a matrix on the right, in which case (0, 0, 1, 0) gets you the 3rd row in the matrix. This is independent from how you store the matrix (row-major vs column-major), so this complicates things - what you need is in the opposite direction of the way you go when you're calculating a particular component of the result.

Comment: So this depends on the order you're doing multiplication (if you treat the vectors as row vectors or column vectors). If things aren't setup so that you can easily extract it, saving a few clock cycles is probably not worth the trouble - I'd go with multiplication, it's probably not going to make a difference.

Comment: Thanks @DMGregory, if Filip wants to answer and take credit, I'm happy to accept it! I actually didn't notice too much of a performance difference by extracting the column, but it is a bit better. I think this will do!